# Unable to run test in cypress

Tags: automation, cypress

After I successfully ran my tests in VS code for cypress I closed the VS studio code. Today when I reopened the visual studio code and tried to run any test, I am getting an error that states "**Could not find a cypress configuration file in this folder**". The picture is pasted below. Would you please let me know what I am missing?

[image]

Comment: Can you add your file structure? Where are you trying to run the Cypress command from?

Comment: If you are using git or something like that, make sure that you are on correct branch.

Answer (score 0):

According to the screen you provided, Cypress try to find config in `/Users/{username}/CypressAutomation/cypress/report/html` directory. It would be helpful if you add file structure to question, but I suppose that you should run it from `/Users/{username}/CypressAutomation/`. You need to change directory, in this case use `cd ../../..` command and then try to run Cypress.